# Why does the dust in the sky make the light shine more or in other words it is visible from far away?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, atmospheric-science

Why does the dust in the sky make the light shine more or in other words it is visible from far away?

[This image shows how light is scattered in dust particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6YO.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6YO.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A uniform dust cloud will make the light source dimmer but it will make the area around the light source appear brighter.

Since human eye measures $log(Q)$, the light source will be perceived very slightly less lit but the dark area around it will **appear** significantly lit, so the total luminosity will appear larger. If we would measure raw luminosity, it will actually decrease. This may be different for non-uniform clouds, though.